# JSON String to NSDictionary with Swift

Tags: ios, json, xcode, swift

I am trying to create a dictionary from data that is held in a server, I receive the data but I cannot convert the data to an `NSDictionary`, I believe it is held in an `NSData` Object

```
let JSONDictionary: Dictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(JSONData!, options: nil, error: &error) as NSDictionary
```

This line of code is the one giving me the problem, it throws a `BAD_EXEC_INSTRUCTION`.

MY Question: How can I turn a `JSON` into an `NSDictionary`?

Comment: Can you post some code showing how your NSData object is declared and where/how you are initializing it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code does not do any error handling. But it can (and if this data comes from a web service, will) fail in multiple ways.

1. You have to make sure that your data object actually exists
2. You have to make sure that the data object can be converted to JSON
3. You have to make sure that the JSON actually contains a Dictionary

You should use Swifts conditional cast and it's optional binding capabilities.
The optional binding `if let JSONData = JSONData` checks that JSONData is not nil. The force unwrap (`JSONData!`) you use might crash if no data could be received.

The optional binding `if let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData` checks if the data could be converted to a JSON object. The conditional cast `as? NSDictionary` checks if the JSON object is actually a dictionary. You currently don't use these checks, you cast the objects as NSDictionary. Which will crash, if the object is not valid json, or if its not a dictionary.

I would recommend something like this:

```
var error: NSError?
if let JSONData = JSONData { // Check 1
    if let json: AnyObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(JSONData, options: nil, error: &error) { // Check 2
        if let jsonDictionary = json as? NSDictionary { // Check 3
            println("Dictionary received")
        }
        else {
            if let jsonString = NSString(data: JSONData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                println("JSON String: \n\n \(jsonString)")
            }
            fatalError("JSON does not contain a dictionary \(json)")
        }
    }
    else {
        fatalError("Can't parse JSON \(error)")
    }
}
else {
    fatalError("JSONData is nil")
}
```

You could merge check 2 and 3 into one line and check if NSJSONSerialization can create a NSDictionary directly:

```
var error: NSError?
if let JSONData = JSONData { // Check 1.
    if let JSONDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(JSONData, options: nil, error: &error) as? NSDictionary { // Check 2. and 3.
        println("Dictionary received")
    }
    else {

        if let jsonString = NSString(data: JSONData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
            println("JSON: \n\n \(jsonString)")
        }
        fatalError("Can't parse JSON \(error)")
    }
}
else {
    fatalError("JSONData is nil")
}
```

Make sure to replace `fatalError` with appropriate error handling in your production code

Answer (score 8):

**Update for Swift 2.**

Now you must use it inside a try catch block.

```
    do {
        let responseObject = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as! [String:AnyObject]
    } catch let error as NSError {
 print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Comment: @zaid-pathan I've canceled your edit because it introduced an issue. If you remove the NSError downcast, you can't call the `localizedDescription` method on `error` anymore. Please avoid making edits which change the code that much anyway. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 4):

Here `jsonResult` will give you the response in `NSDictionary`:

```
let url = NSURL(string: path)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
            println("Task completed")
            if(error != nil) {
                // If there is an error in the web request, print it to the console
                println(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            var err: NSError?
            var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as NSDictionary
            if(err != nil) {
                // If there is an error parsing JSON, print it to the console
                println("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
            }

        })
        task.resume()
```

Comment: The comment in the second error should read: `// If there is an error parsing JSON, this line will never be reached because the code errors out when you try to unwrap a nil value`